# Editing Queries from Mysql Database in Power BI

Tags: mysql, powerbi, relationship

I am creating relationships in Power BI between two tables fetched from a MySQL Database but none of the columns contain  distinct values to enable me create a 'one to many' or 'many to one' relationship. Is there a way to do this without altering the database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in mquery you can make a new column creating a unique-key (distinct values). This unique key you can use to make your relation in PBi. The good thing is the key is created at loading so there is not a performance hit. Many times I use values from differenct columns to create the unique key, I propose you use this technique.

In PBi, click on transform data, now you are in mquery. Select the table(s) and add a new  column based on other columns. The UI is giving enough context to find your way around..

If you end up in a situation that your table does not have unique rows (duplicates), you can also use mquery to filter them out, create a new table or even merge with other tables.

So what you need to remember: mquery can be used to model/manupulate your data so you can do proper reporting.